# how to draw text of different sizes with paint method? Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I need to draw text of different sizes. however below code only gives choice *where* to place text not *how big* it will appear:

```
g.drawText("bla bla", aX, aY);
```

Do I have to use method above and then to scale bitmap into preferred height, or is there some other method to do it which i overlooked? Any example ? Thanks!

```
g.drawText("bla bla", aX, aY, sizeX, sizeY);    <---- something like this?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the text is controlled by the font. You can use [setFont](http://www.java-samples.com/j2me/change-fontsize-and-color-free-j2me-sample-program.htm):

```
Font f1 = Font.getFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_LARGE); 
g.setFont(f1);
g.drawString("BIG FONT", 0, yPos, Graphics.LEFT | Graphics.TOP);
```